# Filters not working

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, filter, migration, product-listing

I migrated a Magento 1.9 site locally on my computer. Everything seems to be okay except for the front end filters. None of the filters (color, price, manufacturer) seem to be working. When I click on a filter, it appends the URL with "...?color=xyz" but still all of the products are shown.

No third party applications have been installed. I have reindexed it using n98 magerun.

Comment: Have your tried reindexing?

Comment: Do you mean admin grid filter or frontend product filter?

Comment: He is talking about frontend filters